# Filter an object from an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am fetching data from an API using axios.
On my invoice details page when I try to get data of only one invoice using this code

```
    const id = props.match.params.id;

    const invoice = useSelector((state) => state.invoices.find(invoice => invoice._id === id));
```

It returns an object or undefined but I only want an object inside an array or an empty array not undefined how should I do that?
When I tried to use .filter method instead of .find, it logged the array into the console infinite time.

Complete code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import backIcon from '../assets/images/icon-arrow-left.svg'
import InvoiceDetailsHeader from './InvoiceDetailsHeader';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
// remove this after adding DB
import data from '../data.json'
import InvoiceCardDetails from './InvoiceCardDetails';

const InvoiceDetails = (props) => {
    const [invoiceData, setInvoiceData] = useState([]);
    const id = props.match.params.id;

    const invoice = useSelector((state) => state.invoices.find(invoice => invoice._id === id));

    useEffect(() => {
        setInvoiceData(invoice);
        // console.log(invoiceData)
    }, [id, invoice]);

    return (
        <div className="mx-auto px-12 py-16 w-full max-w-3xl">
            <Link to="/" className="text-neutral text-xs"><img className="inline -mt-1 mr-4" src={backIcon} alt="back" /> Go back</Link>
            <InvoiceDetailsHeader data={invoiceData} />
            <InvoiceCardDetails data={invoiceData} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default InvoiceDetails
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `find()` method returns `undefined` if element is not found. You can use an if condition to check if `invoice` is undefined, and set it to an empty array if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're setting setInvoiceData(invoice) which is undefined at the very start. so make a check on it

```
 if(invoice){
setInvoiceData([invoice])
}
```

please try this one

Comment: thanks for your help.
It's working as expected

Comment: most welcome, and please mark the answer ticked and useful. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(invoice){
       setInvoiceData([...invoiceData, invoice])
    }
}, [id, invoice]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know if I missed anything, but I don't think it's a good way for invoice to be possible for both objects and empty array. I think a better way is to divide the conditions and render the invoice when the ID is not found.

---

If a filter method is used instead of a find, the filter method returns a new array instance each time. So as the second argument(invoice) of use Effect changes, the update callback of use Effect will continue to be repeated.

```js
const invoice = useSelector((state) => state.invoices.find(invoice => invoice._id === id) ?? []);
```

What you want can be done simply using [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).
However, `[]` also creates a new array instance, so update callback is repeated indefinitely.

So to make what you want work in the current code, please remove the `invoice` from the dependence of useEffect as below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInvoiceData(invoice);
  // console.log(invoiceData)
}, [id]);
```